# How to install mathgifg.sty package on Windows with TeX Live 2013

Tags: packages, installing

How do I install the [`mathgifg` package](http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/fonts/mathgifg) on Windows using TeX Live 2013? I am using `pdflatex`.

Comment: For the record, `tlmgr install mathgifg` does not seem to see it in the package repository.

Comment: Related: [Using the erdc with MiKTeX on Windows (trouble with mathgifg and font setup)](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/49076)